# How to optimally set active/inactive flag based on a date and store id in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe with the following structure (showing the relevant columns):

```
store_price_date: date
store_id: string
```

For every store, I have to set `isActive` column to a value of `X` if the store was open. For example, I have a start and end date (e.g. 2022-01-01, 2023-01-29), and if the store was opened on 2023-01-04 (based on `store_price_date`), the flag should be set to `X`. If it wasn't, it should be empty.

I am dealing with a large dataset (>1TB) so I wanted to ask for an optimal way to do this in PySpark.

Resulting dataframe should have the date (not `store_price_date`), `store_id`, and `isActive` flag.

Example input:

```
+---+------------+------+--+
| store_price_date|store_id
+---+------------+------+--+
| 2022-01-05     |T105|
| 2022-01-07     |T105|
| 2022-01-11     |T105|
| 2022-01-05     |WQ05|
| 2023-01-06     |WQ05|
| 2022-07-05     |RT00|
+---+------------+------+
```

Expected output:

```
+---+------------+------+--+
| date|store_id  | isActive
+---+------------+------+--+
| 2022-01-01|T105|    |
| 2022-01-02|T105|    |
| 2022-01-05|T105|  X |
| 2022-01-06|T105|  X |
| 2022-01-06|WQ05|  X |
| 2022-01-04|WQ05|    |
| 2022-01-05|RT00|  X |
| 2022-01-06|RT00|    |
+---+------------+------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: Input, output and explanation do not match. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and review/edit your post. For example, use a smaller range for start and end date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, sorry for an issue with the question - it's not structured correctly with a bad example input/output data. But, I've managed to find an answer so I'll post everything here if someone needs it in the future.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from typing import List
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def generate_dates(range_list, interval = 60 * 60 * 24, dt_col='date'):
    start, stop = range_list
    temp_df = spark.createDataFrame([(start, stop)], ('start', 'stop'))
    temp_df = temp_df.select([F.col(c).cast('timestamp') for c in ('start', 'stop')])
    temp_df = temp_df.withColumn('stop', F.date_add('stop', 1).cast('timestamp'))
    temp_df = temp_df.select([F.col(c).cast('long') for c in ('start', 'stop')])
    start, stop = temp_df.first()
    df = spark.range(start, stop, interval).select(F.col('id').cast('timestamp').alias(dt_col))
    df = df.withColumn(dt_col, F.to_date(dt_col))
    return df

def get_start_end_dates(start_date: str) -> List[str]:
    return [start_date, str(datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=1))]

dates_list = get_start_end_dates('2022-01-01')
dates_df = generate_dates(dates_list)
data = [("2023-01-01", "T105"), ("2023-01-02", "T105"), ("2023-01-04", "T105"),
       ("2023-01-02", "WQ05"), ("2023-01-08", "WQ05"), ("2023-01-07", "WQ05"),
       ("2023-01-01", "RT00"), ("2023-01-21", "RT00"), ("2023-01-13", "RT00")]

columns = ["store_price_date", "store_id"]

master_df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

master_df = master_df.withColumn("store_price_date", F.to_date("store_price_date"))

data = [("T105",), ("WQ05", ), ("RT00", )]
columns = ["store_id"]
store_df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

df = dates_df.crossJoin(store_df.select('store_id'))
join_cond = [df['date'] == master_df['store_price_date'], df['store_id'] == master_df['store_id']]
output_df = df.join(master_df, join_cond, "leftouter").select(df['*'], master_df['store_price_date'])
output_df = output_df.withColumn('isActive', F.when(F.col('store_price_date').isNotNull(), F.lit('X')).otherwise(None))
```

Example input df's:

```
date_df:
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2022-01-01|
|2022-01-02|
|2022-01-03|
|2022-01-04|
|2022-01-05|
|2022-01-06|
|2022-01-07|
|2022-01-08|
|2022-01-09|
|2022-01-10|
|2022-01-11|
|2022-01-12|
|2022-01-13|
|2022-01-14|
|2022-01-15|
|2022-01-16|
|2022-01-17|
|2022-01-18|
|2022-01-19|
|2022-01-20|
+----------+

Master_df:
+----------------+--------+
|store_price_date|store_id|
+----------------+--------+
|      2023-01-01|    T105|
|      2023-01-02|    T105|
|      2023-01-04|    T105|
|      2023-01-02|    WQ05|
|      2023-01-08|    WQ05|
|      2023-01-07|    WQ05|
|      2023-01-01|    RT00|
|      2023-01-21|    RT00|
|      2023-01-13|    RT00|
+----------------+--------+

Store_df (contains all store id's):

+--------+
|store_id|
+--------+
|    T105|
|    WQ05|
|    RT00|
+--------+
```

Output df:

```
output_df.select('*').filter(F.col('isActive') == 'X').show()
+----------+--------+----------------+--------+
|      date|store_id|store_price_date|isActive|
+----------+--------+----------------+--------+
|2023-01-01|    RT00|      2023-01-01|       X|
|2023-01-21|    RT00|      2023-01-21|       X|
|2023-01-13|    RT00|      2023-01-13|       X|
|2023-01-01|    T105|      2023-01-01|       X|
|2023-01-02|    T105|      2023-01-02|       X|
|2023-01-04|    T105|      2023-01-04|       X|
|2023-01-02|    WQ05|      2023-01-02|       X|
|2023-01-08|    WQ05|      2023-01-08|       X|
|2023-01-07|    WQ05|      2023-01-07|       X|
+----------+--------+----------------+--------+
```

Query plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [date#19, store_id#77, store_price_date#63, CASE WHEN isnotnull(store_price_date#63) THEN X END AS isActive#98]
   +- SortMergeJoin [date#19, store_id#77], [store_price_date#63, store_id#60], LeftOuter
      :- Sort [date#19 ASC NULLS FIRST, store_id#77 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(date#19, store_id#77, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=547]
      :     +- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildLeft, Cross
      :        :- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode, [plan_id=543]
      :        :  +- Project [cast(cast(id#15L as timestamp) as date) AS date#19]
      :        :     +- Range (1640991600, 1675033200, step=86400, splits=1)
      :        +- Project [_1#75 AS store_id#77]
      :           +- Scan ExistingRDD[_1#75]
      +- Sort [store_price_date#63 ASC NULLS FIRST, store_id#60 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(store_price_date#63, store_id#60, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=548]
            +- Project [cast(_1#55 as date) AS store_price_date#63, _2#56 AS store_id#60]
               +- Filter (isnotnull(cast(_1#55 as date)) AND isnotnull(_2#56))
                  +- Scan ExistingRDD[_1#55,_2#56]
```